# python giving TypeError: count takes at least * argument even when arguments are given

Tags: python, arguments, cout

I have following code in which I have given i as an argument to cout() but still  getting `TypeError: count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

```
def is_isogram(s:str):
    for i in s:
        print(i)
        if( str.count(i) > 1): # specified argument , still getting error
            return False
        return True
```

Comment: This code correctly calls `count()` with an argument, so this is not the code you're running.  Show us the real code.

Comment: @JohnGordon actually the error is consisent with their code

Comment: @Chris_Rands How?  That code sample clearly calls `str.count(i)`.

Comment: @JohnGordon They meant `s.count(i)` try `str.count('')` vs `str.count('','')`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I still don't understand what you mean.  The reported error is `count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`, which cannot come from the given code sample `str.count(i)`.

Comment: @JohnGordon `str.count(i)` in this case the *string instance* is missing; i agree the traceback it's a bit non-initiative, but it's the same for everything else, like try `list.append([])`. In reality there a few cases where you should write calls like that, e.g. `str.maketrans` perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.count(i) > 1` should be `s.count(i) > 1`, this will fix your error.

You could use `for i in set(i):` or `collections.Counter` to solve your task more efficiently:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'abbc'
>>> Counter(s).most_common(1)[0][1] == 1
False
```

---

Timings:

```
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzz'  # a worst case?

%timeit Counter(s).most_common(1)[0][1] == 1
13.2 µs ± 27.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit len(set(s)) == len(s)
1.33 µs ± 3.46 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
for i in set(s):
    if s.count(i) > 1:
        break
1.72 µs ± 17.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
for i in s:
    if s.count(i) > 1:
        break
6.78 µs ± 14.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I actually think the most efficient test would be `len(set(s)) == len(s)`

Comment: @FHTMitchell oh yeh possibly (certainly that is more readalble) but i'd have to `timeit` to be sure

Comment: I added some to your answer for fun. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @FHTMitchell Thanks! Counter is surprisingly slow, does it change if you do say `s*10000` for a much longer string? (or rather `s[:-1]*10000+'z'` i gues)

Comment: `s[:-1]*10000+'z'` will still hit the a repeat value (`'a'`) at `27` characters. Since there are only 26 unique characters the best test I reckon is `len(s) <= 26` and `len(set(s)) == len(s)`. Otherwise yes, the `set` method will continue to slow with increased size (`O(N)`) but the last for loop won't.

Comment: @FHTMitchell list.count runs at C speed so is fast for short sequences but the time complexity is much worse than Counter so suffers for longer sequnces, checkout these timings https://pastebin.com/zzeSDw4y